# Having issue with the $id_get['id '] function

Tags: php

I want to be able to call the comment that users make on a picture on the same page as the pic. and when a different page comes up that comment for that pic is displayed also. I am able to that, but I can't seem to call the URL for that pic without changing the actual code.

```
<?
include.....

$picid = $_GET['picid'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pic_info WHERE picid = 'picid1' ");// problem

while($rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)):
$picid = $rows['picid'];
$title = $rows['title'];
$link = $rows['link'];
$description = $rows['description'];
$movie_pic = $rows['movie_pic'];
$source = $rows['source'];

endwhile;

$get_comment = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM comment WHERE picid ='$picid'");// work partially
$comment_count = mysql_num_rows($get_comment);
if ($comment_count>0)
{
while ($com = mysql_fetch_array($get_comment)){
$comment_id = $com['comment_id'];
$name = $com['name'];
$message = $com['message'];
$time_post= $com['time_post'];
$messages .= '<em> on ' .$time_post.'</em><b>   '.$name.'   said.....</b><br/> '.$message.'<hr/>';
}
?>
```

Problem: only works if I change picid1 to some thing else like picid2 or 3 or 4...
work partially :: works when I change picid1 to some thing else like picid2 or 3 or 4...
other than that it comes up saying no comment.

I'm not sure if the problem is at top, cant figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

you are missing a $...

> WHERE picid = **'$picid'**

Soemething like this:

```
$picid = $_GET['picid'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pic_info WHERE picid = '$picid' ");
```

To be in the safe side... I would actually do this

```
$picid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['picid']);
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM pic_info WHERE picid = '$picid' ");
```

[Why? Read here](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysql-php-sql-injection.php)

BTW, if picid is a number type, I would omit the quotes...

```
 WHERE picid = $picid
```

---- EDIT ------

```
if ($comment_count>0)
{
  $messages = ""; //added this
  while ($com = mysql_fetch_array($get_comment)){
    $comment_id = $com['comment_id'];
    $name = $com['name'];
    $message = $com['message'];
    $time_post= $com['time_post'];
    $messages .= '<em> on ' .$time_post.'</em><b>   '.$name.'   said.....</b><br/>'.$message.'<hr/>';
  }
} // added this...
?>
```

Comment: also i been realizing that i get this error message too -- Notice: Undefined variable: messages in for this line                         $messages .= '<em> on ' .$time_post.'</em><b>   '.$name.'   said.....</b><br/> '.$message.'<hr/>'; if i change .= to = the error goes away but then only one comment shows up. how can i get all to show up without the error 
}

Comment: i got it to work, the reason why it happen is because of the endwhile loop statement so i rewrite that section of the code, now i am able to call the video thru the get id function. but for the message error that is still not working.

Comment: "Undefined index: picid" :: double check whether you have "picid=xyz" in query part of your url. Seems it is missing.

Comment: i got it to work, the reason why it happen is because of the endwhile loop statement so i rewrite that section of the code, now i am able to call the video thru the get id function. but for the message error that is still not working. i get this error message too -- Notice: Undefined variable: messages in for this line $messages .= '<em> on ' .$time_post.'</em><b> '.$name.' said.....</b><br/> '.$message.'<hr/>'; if i change .= to = the error goes away but then only one comment shows up. how can i get all to show up without the error }

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the solution for this error message.